# GET / - - - - ms in meanio

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean.io

I have installed the mean stack with the instructions below:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ npm install -g gulp
$ npm install -g bower
$ sudo npm install -g mean-cli
$ mean init testApp
$ cd testApp && npm install
```

Whenever I run the `gulp` command it starts successfully and shows the last line:

```
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
[12:09:03] index.html reloaded.
```

After that if I go to `localhost:3000` the page reloads in an infinite loop and shows the following output on the terminal:

```
Mean app started on port 3000 enter code here`(development) cluster.worker.id: 0
[12:09:03] index.html reloaded.
GET / - - - - ms
GET / - - - - ms
GET / - - - - ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross check permissions on the npm also change owner from root.